# Opera doesn't start in LXC container: "Out of memory"

Tags: ram, lxc, opera

I'm trying to run Opera browser in a LXC container (logged in via `ssh -X`), but it doesn't work:

```
andrea@ue-02:~$ opera
[378:388:0507/165937.131977:FATAL:memory.cc(22)] Out of memory. size=131072
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

The LXC container is a bit different from classical LXC. The only configuration file is `lxc.conf`:

```
lxc.uts.name=ue-02
lxc.net.0.type=veth
lxc.net.0.name=backchan0
lxc.net.0.flags=up
lxc.net.0.link=letce0
lxc.net.0.ipv4.address=10.88.1.2/24
lxc.net.0.veth.pair=aveth.3.0
lxc.net.1.type = empty
lxc.net.1.flags=up

lxc.console.path = none
lxc.tty.max = 1
lxc.pty.max = 128
lxc.cgroup.devices.allow = a
lxc.mount.auto = proc sys cgroup


lxc.autodev = 1
lxc.hook.autodev = /usr/share/emane-model-lte/demo/two_ues/ue-02/lxc.hook.autodev.sh
lxc.apparmor.profile = unconfined
```

Someone could help me?

Thank you very much!!

Andrea

Comment: Are you using a VPN or any extensions? I've spent some time looking around and most people are blaming this on VPN memory leak. Also, can you try to clean your your opera profile and update the app to the latest version so we have a baseline to work from? Finally, please make sure it is Opera 64-bit (assuming your machine is also 64-bit).

Comment: @jwcooper Opera is fresh installed: no profile, no history... Just installed and tried. Yes, it's the 64-bit version (verified by `file /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera`). No VPN or any extensions. Just the LXC container is a bit different from classical LXC. I'm using the demonstration's container you can find at his page: https://github.com/adjacentlink/emane-model-lte. The only configuration file is the `lxc.conf` that I will paste now in the question.

Comment: I'm really not sure then. My next idea would be to try a different container (maybe even use a docker image) and see if that would work. I wasnt able to find anyone else reporting this issue either. Could the container be corrupt? Have you tried to blow it out and download again and then retry?

Comment: @jwcooper Yes, I tried to download again and reinstall, but without success. I know that softwares with GUI can work in this container, because I am using Wireshark for example. I have tried to use Opera in a normal container (created by `sudo lxc-create -t download -n name`) and it works. I repeat: this is a "strange" container, because for example I can see the whole content of my PC from inside the container... but I don't think that it's corrupted.

Comment: You are running LXC containers that are packaged from EMANE LTE. They may set some constraints to the memory for the needs of the emulator. The message says it cannot find 132MB of memory.

Comment: In general, to run GUI applications in a container, it is better to pass the X11 Unix socket to the container. In that way, there are no extra needs of memory for SSH to pass all that data. An example of that, see https://blog.simos.info/how-to-easily-run-graphics-accelerated-gui-apps-in-lxd-containers-on-your-ubuntu-desktop/